# I dont really understand how I make a connection and add data to my SQL database

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a simple website that adds you to a sql database. Right now my database only contains a table that takes in the `firstName`, `lastName` and `email` of a user(this will be added upon later). But my main problem is that I'm not quite sure how to establish a connection.

I know that my php code is surely contains a lot of mistakes but these will hopefully be fixed once I can add users.

I am hosting my sql and apache server through XAMPP.

My jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2knt74r5/

My php code:

```
    <?php

    /*
        IF CITIZEN FORM WAS SUBMITED
    */
    if ($_POST["citEnter"]){
        $title = $_POST["title"];
        $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
        $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
        $email = $_POST["citEmail"];
    }

    /*
        IF ORGANISATION FORM WAS SUBMITED
    */
    if ($_POST["orgEnter"]){
        $title = $_POST["title"];
        $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
        $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
        $email = $_POST["orgEmail"];
    }


    /*
        IF ANONYMOUS FORM WAS SUBMITED
    */
    if ($_POST["anonEnter"]){
        $title = "";
        $firstName = "Anonymous";
        $lastName = "";
        if ($_POST["anonEmail"])
            $email = $_POST["anonEmail"];
        else
            $email = "";
    }
    // I know that I need to establish a connection first..
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ($firstName, $lastName, $email)";

?>
```

Comment: The best place to start is almost always [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) Just make sure you avoid any tutorials you may find that use the `mysql_*` database extension as there lies a complete waste of your time

Comment: @RiggsFolly Dont know the extent of your sarcasm. But if you have never worked with sql before all the terms seems a little overwhelming. I tried looking at w3schools sql tutorial, but they had mysqlite is this the same as the sql that I am using? Are you serious with `mysql_*` will waste my time? Why did you direct me to php data objects? If it is something really fundamental that I am missing here, then tell me so or dont say anything at all. Thanks for nothing.

Comment: So, what RDBMS do you use? MySQL or MS SQL Server or something else?

Comment: XAMPPs  mySQL. Never done anything with databases before. Seems like this site was the wrong place to ask for questions since you apperently need much more experiance before you ask questions

Comment: The `mysql_*` PHP-MySQL database access extension is old. deprecated, and completely removed from PHP7 the latest release of PHP. That is why I suggested you dont try using that. Unfortunately most tutorials out there on t'web do use this extension in there examples. I pointed you to the more Modern PHP-MYSQL database extension called PDO for that reason.

Comment: SO is aimed at code based issues i.e. _this code does not work and I cannot see why_ It is not a place to come for a tutorial or training session. That is why my comment said, _at least try and start the coding yourself_ There are still 100's of tutorials and books available to get a guy from zero to a basic understanding.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Alright, I am sorry about that. I thought that you were being sarcastic and directed me to a random php manual page. I will give it a read

Answer (score 0):

to establish database  connection in php you could use PDO class.
for example

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name;user=username;password=password");
$sql = "Insert into table xyz(z,b) values('a','b')";
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: Why are you preparing a query that has no parameters in it? The OP is a newbie, dont show him bad code.